# How to send dynamic content email without cron job

Tags: php, email, cron, mailchimp

I have a site where many user registered.There is some activities for each registered user 
I want to sent them a weekly stats email for their each week activity.

Each weekly mail have weekly stats for user registered

How I can sent them weekly mail without cron job.

Is it possible to send weekly dynamic mail using mail chaimp or if not why ?

Or any suggestion How i can implement that

Comment: Why not use `cron`?  You don't *need* to use `cron` specifically, but you do *need* to use some sort of scheduler (which is what `cron` is).  If MailChimp provides scheduling then, yes, you can use that.  If they don't, then no you can't.  The point is to logically separate the *sending of the email* (an implementation concern) from the *scheduling of the process* (a workflow concern).

Answer (score 2):

You could use an online cron service to do that. Simply set it to fire your script every week....

- [EasyCron](https://www.easycron.com/)
- [SetCronJob](https://www.setcronjob.com/)
- [My Web Cron](http://www.mywebcron.com/)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to add some code like this (untested!) to your web page so it runs whenever the site is visited:

```
<?php

$fp = @fopen('.lastjob', "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {

    $lastjob = fgets($fp);

    if (!$lastjob || (time() - $lastjob) > 604800) {

        // send out the emails here

        ftruncate($fp, 0);
        fwrite($fp, time());
        fflush($fp);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

    }

}

fclose($fp);
```

It checks whether the last job was performed more than a week ago, and if so, it sends out the emails.

Comment: In theory, it's a good idea, but in reality, I think it will put a lot of stress on the server if there are a few hundred visits per hour....